# Python start and manage external processes from Django

Tags: python, django

I'm in need of a way to execute external long running processes from a web app written in Django and Python.

Right now I'm using Supervisord and the API. My problem with this solution is that it's very static. I need to build the commands from my app instead of having to pre configure Supervisord with all possible commands. The argument and the command is dynamic.

I need to execute the external process, save a pid/identifier and later be able to check if it's still alive and running and stop the process.

I've found https://github.com/mnaberez/supervisor_twiddler to add processes on the fly to supervisord. Maybe that's the best way to go?

Any other ideas how to best solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at this post:

[Processing long-running Django tasks using Celery + RabbitMQ + Supervisord + Monit](http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2012/01/27/processing-long-running-django-tasks-using-celery-rabbitmq-supervisord-monit/)

As the title says, there are a few additional components involved (mainly celery and rabbitMQ), but these are good and proven technologies for this kind of requirement.

Comment: For anyone coming here recently (as of 2023), the article link above has died.

The below link should work (it did for me):

https://hiddentao.com/archives/2012/01/27/processing-long-running-django-tasks-using-celery-rabbitmq-supervisord-monit